# Recursively Retrieve C/C++ Include Dependecies in SCons

Tags: c++, c, scons, c-preprocessor, build-system

We are developing a tweaked version of a SCons action for C/C++ files that uses the dependencies already found by the builtin C/C++ scanner to automatically create a list of directories that is put into `CPPPATH`.

Our currently solution uses recursive calls to `get_found_includes()` defined at

http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Node.Node-class.html#get_found_includes

However we get exceptions from this logic complaining about the `path` argument sent to `get_found_includes()` being `None`. These calls are called somewhere deeper down in the SCons (recursion) logic and not directly by our own calls to `get_found_includes`.

Note that we are only interested in the cached dependencies already calculated by the corresponding scanner. It would be nice to have a variant of `get_found_includes()` that return only these nodes without having to guess the correct value of argument `path`.

Further how does `get_implicit_deps()` defined at

http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Node.Node-class.html#get_implicit_deps

differ from `get_found_includes` in this regard? I've read their descriptions a couple of times but cannot figure out the difference of their menaings meanings.

Is there a better way to solve this?

If we want to hack this together ourselves I guess all the dependencies are stored in the graph as node properties that can be traversed.

Comment: Can you explain the "why"? Perhaps if we understand the reason you want to do this, we can provide another way to do it?